# Can algorithms be made compatible with expression templates?

Tags: c++, expression-templates, range-v3

Suppose I have some array-based code that is enabled to be used by expression templates. E.g., I have `operator[]` for these arrays overloaded and also have overloaded the arithmetic operator `+` etc.

Now I would like to let the STL algorithm `any_of` run on such arrays. The simple way is to do

```
ExprArray<double, N> b, c; // init etc. 
auto a = b + c;            // for (auto i = 0; i < N; ++i) { a[i] = b[i] + c[i]; }
auto res = std::any_of(begin(a), end(a), SomePred{});
```

Of course, I would like to be able to short-circuit the computation and have a modified (range-based) `lib::any_of` that does

```
// only compute b[i] + c[i] until SomePred is satisified
auto res = lib::any_of(b + c, SomePred{}); // write as explicit loop over b[i] + c[i]
```

Writing `lib::any_of` in terms of `operator[]` on its input will do that job, the same as it was done for the overloaded `operator+`. However, this would require similar reimplementations of all STL algorithms that I could possibly run on such arrays.

**Question**: So suppose I want to re-use existing range-based algorithms (Boost.Range, range-v3) **by only modifying the `ExprArray iterators`**. Is it possible to modify the `ExprArray` iterator `operator*` and `operator++` in such a way that this is transparent to range-based algorithms?

```
// only compute b[i] + c[i] until SomePred is satisified
// needs to eventually dispatch to 
// for (auto i = 0; i < N; ++i)
//     if (SomePred(b[i] + c[i])) return true;
// return false;
auto res = ranges::any_of(b + c, SomePred{});
```

So if the algorithm version actually is implemented in terms of iterators, the loop `for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it)` needs `*it` to be aware of the fact that it needs to compute `b[i] + c[i]`, and `++it` has to know that it needs to do `++i`.

Comment: Stopping when the predicate is true should be a natural thing to do for `std::any_of`, have you checked that it doesn't already does that? (You can do that by passing a lambda that prints the values it receives as the predicate.)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the stopping is not really the problem, it's the lazy computation of the expression template and its begin/end iterators. If I only have overloaded `operator[]`, I need an iterator based implementation to be aware of the fact that it receives an expression template and to translate `*it` to the appropriate `expr[i]`. The question is, can `operator*` of the iterator do that kind of work for me?

Comment: @TemplateRex please note that the question is about algorithm c++ library not about algorithm design, so the algorithm tag is inappropriate

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev thanks, I wasn't aware of this somewhat narrow scope.

Comment: Since you're the one who writes the iterator class (I assume), you can have it do pretty much anything you need.

Comment: @Angew true, but it needs to poke in the dark at the algorithm to know which kind of iterator expressions are actually used in the implementation. E.g. to translate the iterator based loop to an index-based loop etc.

Comment: @TemplateRex Not at the *implementation* of the algorithm, but at the *requirements* for the iterator categories, I'd say. That is, what expressions are allowed on an iterator according to category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question seems to reduce to "Can I implement iterators for my expression templates?" which I think is fairly straightforward. Assuming that "expression templates" know their `size` and have overloaded `operator[]` an iterator simply needs to hold a reference to the expression object and an offset into the range it represents:

```
template <class Expr>
class iterator {
public:
  using iterator_category = ranges::random_access_iterator_tag;
  using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
  using value_type = typename Expr::value_type;

  iterator() = default;
  constexpr iterator(Expr& e, difference_type i) :
    expr_{&e}, i_{i} {}

  constexpr bool operator==(const iterator& that) const {
    return assert(expr_ == that.expr_), i_ == that.i_;
  }
  constexpr bool operator!=(const iterator& that) const {
    return !(*this == that);
  }
  // Similarly for operators <, >, <=, >=

  value_type operator*() const {
    return (*expr_)[i_];
  }
  value_type operator[](difference_type n) const {
    return (*expr_)[i_ + n];

  iterator& operator++() & { ++i_; }
  iterator operator++(int) & { auto tmp = *this; ++*this; return tmp; }
  // Similarly for operator--

  iterator operator+(difference_type n) const {
    return iterator{expr_, i_ + n};
  }
  // Similarly for operators -, +=, and -=

  friend iterator operator+(difference_type n, const iterator& i) {
    return i + n;
  }

private:
    Expr* expr_;
    difference_type i_;
};
```

Now you simply have to arrange for "Expression templates" to have `begin` and `end` members that return `iterator{*this, 0}` and `iterator{*this, size()}`.

Comment: thanks, it even works for STL two-legged iterator algorithms, because `end()` does not have to access `operator[]` and can simply use the array size `N`. I was worried I had to compute the expression twice for both `begin` and `end`, but a range-wrapper will just store the expression template and dispatch both iterators.

Answer (score 2):

The question here is what `b+c` returns. If it returns a real `ExprArray`, you can't really have lazy evaluation. The array needs to be filled. You can't store references to `b` and `c` since you have no idea about their lifetime.

However, if it returns a `LazyAddition` whose *conversion* to `ExprArray` performs the addition, then it's trivial to see that `LazyAddition::iterator` can implement lazy addition as well. The risk here is `auto a = b+c` - this will create a `LazyAddition` object with pending references, not an `ExprArray` object.

Things get really nasty if you try to implement the `ExprArray` as a smart pointer behind the scenes. Sure, you could implement Copy-On-Write so that `b+c` is an ExprArray which keeps pointer to both original arrays. But as soon as you call `T& ExprArray<T>::operator[]` the COW will kick in, and copy the *whole* array on a single element *read* ! (C++ operator overloading rules on `const` do not work well for `operator[]`, the const version gets selected when the argument itself is const, not when used for read access)

Comment: Re the lifetime issue: when calling `ranges::any_of(b+c, Pred{})` just assume that `b` and `c` are alive for the duration of the algorithm.

Comment: "Just assume" is why I said there is a risk. You can't distinguish between `b+c` and `b+c`, even if one occurs in `ranges::any_of(b+c, Pred{})` and the other in `auto a = b+c`. it's up to you to decide if the risk is acceptable.

Comment: I am using the example from Vandevoorde & Josuttis (ch 18 in their Templates book), where `operator=` copies alle elements from the rhs. The expression templates in that example all store the lhs and rhs arguments by reference in order to lazily compute the entire expression tree. So `b+c` is a lazy expression and accessing `operator[]` will only compute a single element, unless of course there is aliasing and `c` is a shifted version of `b`.

Comment: BTW, in the V&J example, they have a `template<class Rep=RawArray> ExprArray` template where `Rep` can indeed be a `LazyAddition` class. So `b+c` and similar expressions really are all `ExprArray`s, and there is no danger of having dangling references as long as you stay in local scope when passing expressions to algorithms.